# C++ winapi read from shared memory to std::string

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory, stdstring

I have a reading process with access to shared memory. Another (writing) process did write data to that shared memory using

```
CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, data.data(), data.size());
```

with data being an `std::string` and `pBuf` being a `PVOID` of size `size` created by `MapViewOfFile()`. `data` contains a file loaded from disk by the writing process.

Is there any way I can get the `data` as an `std::string` when reading from the shared memory using `MapViewOfFile`? I tried some approaches I've found here on SO (like simply casting the resulting `PVOID` in the reading process to a `char*`), but whichever approach I tried, the resulting `size()` is always equal to 4 while the initial data is a lot bigger.

Comment: How do you expect the string's `size()` to be magically updated then something is read into its raw buffer? Also, string owns it's buffer. For non woning "view" (it's even in the name of WinApi function!) it's more appropriate to use string_view as suggested below.

Comment: No you can't really make a `std::string` object out of that memory. But you could probably use [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) instead.

Comment: `string::size()` doesn't include the null-terminator so how are you to know how long the string is? Either the null-terminator needs to be copied as well or you need to pass the size of the string somehow.

Comment: @Jdv If you don't have `std::string_view` available, you can get a `std::string` by casting the mapped pointer to `char*` and passing it to the `std::string` constructor that takes `const char* s` and `size_type count` parameters as input. It works fine, despite your claim that it doesn't. You just need to know the `size` of the data that is stored in the mapped memory.